# Combine Two Different Data Types in a Data Frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I realize that there may not be a way to do this in R as my understanding is that all values in a vector need to be of the same data type.

I have a data frame with two columns, the first is the date, the second is closing price for a given stock on that date.  I want to add a row at the bottom with the label in the first column "SD" and the value of the Standard deviation of the price changes.

I am able to do the calculation just fine for the standard deviation, however, R is not happy when I try and add the "SD" label in the first column at the bottom.  The first column is formatted as.Date and I would like to keep it that way if possible.  If not, I would at least like it to display looking like a date so I can read the data easily.

Is there a way to do this?

Here is some sample data:

```
Date          AAPL    
1  2014-01-21 549.07
2  2014-01-22 551.51
3  2014-01-23 556.18
4  2014-01-24 546.07
5  2014-01-27 550.50
6  2014-01-28 506.50
7  2014-01-29 500.75
8  2014-01-30 499.78
9  2014-01-31 500.60
10 2014-02-03 501.53
11 2014-02-04 508.79
12 2014-02-05 512.59
13 2014-02-06 512.51
14 2014-02-07 519.68
15 2014-02-10 528.99
16 2014-02-11 535.96
17 2014-02-12 535.92
18 2014-02-13 544.43
19 2014-02-14 543.99
20 2014-02-18 545.99
21 2014-02-19 537.37
```

I would like it to look like this, with the SD info in the last row:

```
Date          AAPL    
1  2014-01-21 549.07
2  2014-01-22 551.51
3  2014-01-23 556.18
4  2014-01-24 546.07
5  2014-01-27 550.50
6  2014-01-28 506.50
7  2014-01-29 500.75
8  2014-01-30 499.78
9  2014-01-31 500.60
10 2014-02-03 501.53
11 2014-02-04 508.79
12 2014-02-05 512.59
13 2014-02-06 512.51
14 2014-02-07 519.68
15 2014-02-10 528.99
16 2014-02-11 535.96
17 2014-02-12 535.92
18 2014-02-13 544.43
19 2014-02-14 543.99
20 2014-02-18 545.99
21 2014-02-19 537.37
22 SD         0.0217
```

Thank you.

Comment: It all depends on what exactly you're trying to do. Tell us more! Why **must** SD be a string in the Date column? There are many creative alternatives.

Comment: If you found my answer useful (or any other), please click 'accept'.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can't mix different types (Date and string) in one column, and you can't kludge 'SD' into Date type. However, here are some possibilities:

**1) represent Date as string** too, that allows 'SD' too; this can actually work well with your specific date format *yyyy-mm-dd* since the sort order will be correct. Just beware this would mess up ddply/aggregating the date unless you specifically exclude the SD row (by row indices, or test that as.Date(...) conversion works).

2) or you could **directly use row.names** to get you that string label, which allows you to access the SD row directly as df['SD',] :

```
# Lose any existing row.names
row.names(df) = NULL
# Now directly append your SD row when you compute it:
df['SD',] = c('NA', sd(df$AAPL, na.rm=TRUE))
# Or else (less elegant) kludge the row.name onto existing SD row.
row.names(df)[21] = 'SD'
 [1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5" "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10" "11" "12" "13" "14" "15" "16" "17"
[18] "18" "19" "20" "SD"
```

Hijacking row.names like this is possibly bad form and limiting, since any indexing or transform operation, conversion to matrix/array etc/ will drop the 'SD'. It's your call. Obviously we can only have one 'SD' row in the entire dataframe, so we can't do multiple months.

3) or you could **insert a new string column** which would be '' for everything except 'SD' row. That way you could reference the SD row fairly elegantly row as df[df$SD=='SD', ...] without polluting the date field. Put NA in the Date field so it doesn't get picked up by aggregations. This approach may be cleaner, avoids the pitfalls of option 2). Another major advantage is preserve 'Date' column as Date type (advantages: being able to directly apply any of the Date functions to it; automatic plot labeling and sorting).

Let's step back from the syntax of whether you can kludge this into a dataframe, and consider what you are trying to achieve - what exactly is the purpose of this 'SD' entry: a label, a row index, a row or column to assist locating the SD...?

4) **if you only want to show a table with an SD row** (and not actually insert an SD row in the dataframe), you can achieve that with *aggregate/ddply/summarize* and/or *table*.

*ddply(df, .(Date), summarize, SD=sd(AAPL))*

So: it all depends on what exactly you're trying to do. Tell us more!

Comment: Thanks for all of your comments.  The ultimate goal is to get a csv file that I can open in excel that has a column of tickers and a column of their 20 day SD.  This can be done without all of the questions I am asking and is probably what I should just do.  The reason I wanted to make the combination of SD and date was for data verification purposes, to make sure no data points are missing for any of the stocks.  Again, this can be down without adding the SD to the data frame.

Comment: Option 4) then (or else 1), if you don't mind converting 'Date' column to string)